# Auto generating new JPanels onto a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm currently working on a blog/forum portal as a school project for University.

I'm working with Swing as the GUI.

My question is if it's possible to auto generate an already pre-made `JPanel` class onto a `JFrame` so that it looks like the questions on the main page of stackoverflow.

So basically when a post is created it goes into the database -> I use a getter method to fill the info on the panel and then it auto generate itself onto the frame so that I don't need to create several fixed panels onto the frame.

So if there are no posts the page would be blank. When a new post is created it shows up as the first post, the next one lies over that one and so on so forth.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Use a `JList` instead of multiples panels. *"Is it possible to do this in Netbeans?"* If it's possible to do it in Netbeans, it's possible to do it in any other IDE. The code editor is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do this?

Of course, it is possible.

**First**, you need to extend `JPanel` to contain the components that you need. This `JPanel` subclass will contain all the labels, buttons, etc, needed to represent the data in the way that you want. Example:

```
public class CommentPanel extends JPanel {
    private final JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel();
    private final JLabel timestampLabel = new JLabel();
    // etc...
}
```

**Next**, this new class should have a way to set the component states using your model object. *This step is optional*, but will give a lot of convenience in doing so. Example:

```
public void setComment(Comment comment) {
    // appearance
    usernameLabel.setText(comment.getUser().getName());
    timestampLabel.setText(comment.getDate());
    commentText.setText(comment.getContent());

    // button behavior
    editButton.setActionListener(e -> editComment(comment));
    deleteButton.setActionListener(e -> deleteComment(comment));
}
```

**Next** is you need a container in your parent container, like your `JFrame` to hold the would-be generated custom panels. A panel with a controlled `LayoutManager` would be perfect for this.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private final JPanel commentHolder = new JPanel();
    // etc...
    // add `commentHolder` to this frame
}
```

**Lastly**, you need to instantiate the custom panels and set the data. If you created a method that wraps the logic of setting the data (the optional step), this will be a one-liner.

```
List<Comment> comments = fetchAllFromDb();
for (Comment comment : comments) {
    // instantiate the custom panel
    CommentPanel commentPanel = new CommentPanel();

    // set the panel states and behavior
    commentPanel.setComment(comment);

    // add the created panel to the parent using the holder
    commentHolder.add(commentPanel);
}
```